# how to work out a very confusing integral

Tags: fourier-series

i am learning fourier series and i am stuck on an integral.

So i am looking for $$a_n={1\over\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)\ dx ={1\over\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{( \pi-x)^2}{4}\cos(nx)\ dx$$

$$={1\over4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} ( \pi-x)^2\cos(nx)\ dx$$

I know that the answer is $ \frac{1}{n^2}$ but would really like someone to show me and explain a simple way of working this out as i am going to have exam questions like this and so assuming there must be a simple way of working this out..

Many thanks

Comment: The simple way is brute for. Integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an integral of a product of a polynomial and a sine/cosine. That is something we can fruitfully apply integration by parts to, the trigonometric functions switch between sine and cosine, and differentiating reduces the degree of the polynomial, until after finitely many steps, we reach a constant and are left with a pure integral over a sine or cosine. Let's ignore the constant factor, and just integrate:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} (x-\pi)^2\cos (nx)\,dx &= \left[(x-\pi)^2\frac{\sin (nx)}{n} \right]_0^{2\pi} - \frac2n \int_0^{2\pi} (x-\pi)\sin (nx)\,dx\\
&= \frac2n \int_0^{2\pi} (x-\pi)(-\sin (nx))\,dx\\
&= 2\left[(x-\pi)\frac{\cos (nx)}{n^2}\right]_0^{2\pi} - \frac{2}{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos (nx)\,dx\\
&= 2\left[\pi\frac{\cos (2n\pi)}{n^2} - (-\pi)\frac{\cos 0}{n^2}\right]
- \frac{2}{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos (nx)\,dx\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{n^2} - \frac{2}{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos (nx)\,dx\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{n^2} - \left[\frac{2}{n^3}\sin (nx)\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{n^2}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: The answer is $1/n^2$?

Comment: Yes, you have the constant factor $\dfrac{1}{4\pi}$, which I dropped as empty baggage. I computed only the integral.

Comment: Sorry i am a little confused.. how do i get to $1/n^2$ then?

Comment: I computed $\int_0^{2\pi} (x-\pi)^2\cos (nx)\,dx$, and obtained the value $\dfrac{4\pi}{n^2}$. Your Fourier-coefficient is $\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (x-\pi)^2\cos (nx)\,dx$, and $\frac{1}{4\pi}\cdot \frac{4\pi}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: He took out the 1/4pi to make solving it easier to see.

Comment: ah amazing thank you!! sorry i am only just learning this topic of fourier! i see that now, thanks!! :)

Comment: this question was part of a question i asked about an hour ago, no one explained their working properly and some even started off with the wrong answer making me extremely confused

Answer (score 0):

You can observe that
$$
\int x\cos x\,dx=x\sin x-\int \sin x\,dx=x\sin x+\cos x
$$
(integrating by parts).

Similarly
\begin{align}
\int x^2\cos x\,dx &= x^2\sin x-\int 2x\sin x\,dx\\
&=x^2\sin x+2x\cos x-2\int\cos x\,dx\\
&=x^2\sin x+2x\cos x-2\sin x
\end{align}

Now
$$
\int(\pi-x^2)\cos(nx)\,dx=
\pi^2\int\cos(nx)\,dx-2\pi\int x\cos(nx)\,dx+\int x^2\cos(nx)\,dx
$$
and the integrals are computable with the simple substitution $t=nx$.

Comment: I know this already but this isnt leading me to the correct answer?

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews Then you're making some mistakes in the computations.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\Large a_{n}}&={1 \over 4\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \pars{\pi - x}^{2}\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x
={\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x^{2}\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\left.{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over 2\pi}\totald[2]{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\pars{\mu x}\,\dd x\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ n}
={\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over 2\pi}\totald[2]{}{\mu}
\bracks{{\sin\pars{\mu\pi} \over \mu}}_{\mu = n}
={\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over 2\pi}\bracks{%
{-\pi^{2}\sin\pars{\mu\pi} \over \mu} - 2\,{\pi\cos\pars{\pi\mu} \over \mu^{2}}
+
6\,{\sin\pars{\pi\mu} \over \mu^{3}}}_{\mu = n}
=
{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over 2\pi}\bracks{-\,{2\pi\cos\pars{n\pi} \over n^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#0000ff}{\Large{1 \over n^{2}}}
\end{align}